# how to write an expression in SSRS to send a Dataset row to the bottom

Tags: reporting-services

This question may have been answered already but I failed to find the answer.
I am trying to write an expression in SSRS so that a specific dataset row can be sent to the bottom while rendering the report . Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to add a calculated field in your dataset then group by that field in the grouping. Please note, this calculation will run over every record in the scope the calculated field is defined.